# Debugging code that's being tested in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, debugging, visual-studio-2010

I am having some problems with a given test, that I'd like to debug the code that is being tested, while the test runs.

Is this possible?

If yes, how can I just debug this one test? I can only see options for running or the whole solution, or the whole set of tests in the current context or all impacted tests. I'd like to just run this one test, if possible!

I'm running Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a breakpoint in the test and run the test with debug - use the test explorer to select just that test and "run selected".

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182470.aspx) MSDN page (How to: Run Automated Tests from Microsoft Visual Studio).

Comment: Or you can set a breakpoint, click on the test, and then click *Test/Debug/Tests in Current Context* from the menu bar. That will also debug a single test.